# How to convert datetime column to datetimeoffset in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a query which selects customer details from a table. That table contains a `Created_Time` column as `datetime` datatype. While selecting, I want to cast this column to `datetimeoffset` in SQL Server 2005.

Query:

```
select 
    Cust_ID, SubTitle, Summary, PreOrdered, Created_Time -- this column
from 
    Cust_Summary_PreOrder_Info
```

I want to achieve this SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Sql server 2005 does not have datetimeoffset. It's added in 2014 version.

Comment: @ZoharPeled . . . `datetimeoffset` was added in SQL Server 2008:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289(v=sql.100).aspx.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: actually, `DATETIMEOFFSET` was added in SQL Server **2008** - but it's not available in 2005 for sure.

Comment: oops, my mistake was because of [this msdn page.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Didn't see the other versions link (though I did look for it...) Still, not available in 2005 so...

Comment: can we create a user defined function to do the operation which is being done in datetimeoffset datatype. is it possible..?

Comment: You can use [DATEADD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) to add/substract the time zone offset.